# Какую пользу в этом коде несет цикл?

Tags: javascript, html, циклы, queryselectorall

Вот мой код. Не совсем понятно как здесь работает цикл.

```js
let gas = document.querySelectorAll('.gas');
for(let i = 0; i < gas.length; i++) {
    gas[i].onclick = function() {
        let gallons = document.querySelector('.gallons').value;
        let amount = this.getAttribute('data');
        console.log(gallons * amount);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" class='gallons'>
<div>
   <button class="gas" data='1.2'>A 92</button>
   <button class="gas" data='1.6'>A 95</button>
   <button class="gas" data='1.9'>A 98</button>
</div>
```

Получается, что без клика на какую-либо из кнопок тело цикла не будет работать и `for` будет просто перебирать элементы "вхолостую". А вот по клику на одну из кнопок запускается функция, которая находится в теле цикла.

Но мне не понятно как js понимает на какую именно кнопку мы нажали. Цикл-то успел отработать и перебрать все элементы еще до нажатия кнопки. Какую пользу здесь несет цикл?

Comment: Очевидно, цикл нужен только для того, чтобы повесить обработчик клика на каждый элемнт. А какая именно кнопка нажата, определяется через `this` внутри функции

Answer (score 2):

"тело цикла" присваивает обработчик события `onclick` и все. И оно (тело) делает это очень хорошо. А код внутри обработчика будет выполняться по щелчку.

"на какую именно кнопку"

```
let amount = this.getAttribute('data');
             ^^^^
```

Comment: вот! отличный развёрнутый ответ! ведь умеете же!